# How to Get TCP Socket Id When it's connect to server

Tags: node.js, sockets, npm, tcp, tcpsocket

My question is, **How to Get TCP Socket Id When it's connect to server.**

I have code like this,

```
const net = require('net');

const server = net.createServer();
server.listen(port, host, async() => {
    console.log('Server is running on port 6633');
});

server.on('connection', async function(sock) {

   console.log('sockId: ',sock.id); // It's give me undefined

}
```

**So, How to Get Socket Id in TCP Connection in NodeJS.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for my own particular need when addressing this, I just created a map with some user identifier and the websocket itself.

otherwise you can use the request header req.headers['sec-websocket-key']

```
let socketMap = new Map()
server.on('connection', async function(sock, req) {
   console.log('sockId: ',sock.id); // It's give me undefined
   socketMap.set(req.headers['sec-websocket-key'], sock)
}
```